# Use Excel VBA to send Skype messages to an EXISTING group

Tags: excel, vba, chat, skype

I found this code to create a chat to a **new** group in skype

1) I need to be able to send a message to an **existing** skype group.

2) I get an 'Object required' error when I run the below code (when it gets to line 9) which I don't undertand.

Can someone help me with these two queries?

```
Sub Test2()

  Dim aSkype As SKYPE4COMLib.Skype
  Dim oMembers As SKYPE4COMLib.UserCollection
  Set aSkype = New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype
  Dim oChat As Chat
  Dim skUser As SKYPE4COMLib.User

  Set oMembers = CreateObject("Skype4COM.UserCollection")

  oMembers.Add (oSkype.User("skypeuser1"))
  oMembers.Add (oSkype.User("skypeuser2"))
  oMembers.Add (oSkype.User("skypeuser3"))

  Set oChat = oSkype.CreateChatMultiple(oMembers)
  oChat.OpenWindow
  oChat.Topic = "Group Chat Topic"
  oChat.SendMessage "automated message"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim aSkype As SKYPE4COMLib.Skype
    Set aSkype = New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype

    Dim oChat As Chat
    Dim oMembers As Object
    Dim skUser As SKYPE4COMLib.User

    Set oMembers = CreateObject("Skype4COM.UserCollection")
    oMembers.Add aSkype.User("username1")
    oMembers.Add aSkype.User("username2")


    Set oChat = aSkype.CreateChatMultiple(oMembers)
    oChat.OpenWindow
    oChat.Topic = "Your Group Chat Topic"
    oChat.SendMessage "automated message"

End Sub
```

Comment: In your code, oSkype is not declared. that's why it does not work.